# Angular 1.5 components and ui-router 1.0: Add attributes to inserted dom element

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-material

In Angular 1.5, the .component() was introduced and seems to be considered good practice. I am currently migrating to ui-router 1.0 which allows (and recommends) routing to components.
So I refactored a controller/template route to a component router which works great: The component "example" gets injected to the ui-view container in its own DOM node:

However that breaks my layout (using angular material). The workaround i used is simply copying and using css classes angular material uses for  layout on the inserted node. However, i consider this a "hacky" solution: What if angular material changes it's layout module for example?

A better solution would be to add layout attributes or even a css class to the "example" element. But how can i do that? Is that even possible?

I think this question is related to the following, where i provided a workaround for the specific problem. But I am interested in a more generic solution: [Using angular component breaks material layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37735437/using-angular-component-breaks-material-layout)

Comment: facing the same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced the same problem in my Angular 1.5 project where I also use angular-ui-router and Angular Material components. One possible solution is simply using [string-based binding](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component) where you bind two attributes into your component: **layout** and **flex**. You can give the values for these two bound attributes (usually '**row**' and '**100**' respecively) as you specify your ui-routing state in the following way:

```
var exampleState = {
    name: 'examplestate',
    url: '/',             // change this to your desired path
    component: 'example',
    resolve: {
        layout: function () {
            return 'row'; // you can change this value depending on your UI requirements
        },
        flex: function () {
            return '100'; // you can change this value depending on your UI requirements
        }
    }
};
```

In the config method of your module, you define your exampleState in the standard way:

```
$stateProvider.state(exampleState);
```

Finally, in the component definition, as you define your bindings, you add these two attributes to the list of bound attributes.
Example in Typescript:

```
export class ExampleComponent implements ng.IComponentOptions {

    public bindings: any;
    public controller: any;
    public template: string;

    constructor() {
        this.bindings = {
            layout: '@',
            flex: '@'
        };
        this.controller = ExampleComponentController;
        this.template = ExampleViewTemplate;
    }
}
```

You can add this component to your angular module in the usual way:

```
.component('example', new ExampleComponent());
```

This will result in the following HTML element in the DOM (created by angular-ui-router automatically):

```
<example layout="row" flex="100" class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope layout-row flex-100">
```

So in this way you don't need to insert any manual CSS styling in your code. You are using the standard Angular Material attributes on your component-element.

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for your suggestion and sorry for the late reply. Your solution is very useful indeed.